# How to fill values with different datatypes dynamically? C#

Tags: c#, smtp, console-application, smtpclient

I made an SMTP Console Application and now i'm trying to put all checks together to avoid too many "almost" repetitive if statements.

So I made a foreach loop to try to fill all the values I implemented at the beginning with an AppConfig file.

```
            int port = 0;
            bool useCredentials = false;
            string username = "";
            string password = "";
            bool useSsl = false;
            string receiver = "";
            string sender = "";
            string subject = "";
            string body = "";

            bool error = false;

            string[] values = { "smtpServer", "port", "useCredentials", "username", "password", "useSsl", "receiver", "sender", "subject", "body" };

            foreach(var val in values)
            {
                if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[val] == null || ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[val].Length == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(val+" is null");
                    error = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    {
                        //i want the val to be filled, so first smtpServer then port then useCredentials and so on...
                        val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[val]?.ToString();
                    }
                    
                    Console.WriteLine(val);
                }
            }
```

How can i fill the value for each field i implemented at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i think you need to change your mind to objective programming.

Create class:

```
public class AppSettings
{
            public int port {get; set;}
            public bool useCredentials {get; set;}
            public string username {get; set;}
            public string password {get; set;}
            public bool useSsl {get; set;}
            public string receiver {get; set;}
            public string sender {get; set;}
            public string subject {get; set;}
            public string body = {get; set;}
            public bool error = {get; set;}
}
```

And do not use foreach, you dont need that. You want to Deserialize your configuration to this object, so:

```
var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);
var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
```

and then you can use it as `appSettings.port`